# How to DROP a table or stream in KSQL when topic was dropped first

Tags: apache-kafka, stream, ksqldb

Using KSQL (Confluent: Version: 5.0.1) I'm able to drop a table / stream normally (using `DROP [TABLE|STREAM]`) `<NAME>` when the linked topic exist and when it is registered (Registered=true).

However, if the topic is dropped first (Registered=false) then the associated stream or table can't be dropped with KSQL pointing out that "No topic with name Foo was registered".

The problem is that the stream / table still shows in the list and no new stream / table can be added using the same name.

Is there any way to delete them after the topic was dropped?

Answer (score 6):

From the official documentation, I would do it like this:

```
SHOW QUERIES;
```

Write down the QueryID;

```
TERMINATE <QueryID>;

DROP TABLE <tablename>;
```

[See documentation...]

- https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/create-a-table/#delete-a-ksqldb-table
- https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/terminate/

Comment: You can run the DESCRIBE YOUR_STREAM_NAME command to find query id of specific STREAM. Query id exist at sourceDescription->writeQueries->id in the query result JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer, or at least in the right direction.

You need to re-register the topic with the stream.  After a bit of hacking around, I managed to reattach my topics to streams, the drop the streams.

```
REGISTER TOPIC <ksql_topic_name> WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='<kafka_topic_name>', VALUE_FORMAT='<format>');
```

Then,

```
DROP STREAM <stream_name>;
```

I don't know if this works in all cases, but it got me back to where I want to be.  If anyone else can iterate on this and find a more robust solution I would like to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wrestling with these type issues for a while.  Here's where I'm at, from my notes:

Having trouble deleting streams/tables/topics?  Delete them in zookeeper:

- Shut down any producers or consumers associated with topics you'll be deleting
- Attempt to drop your tables and streams from KSQL CLI
- Shut down KSQL server
- Delete topics with 'kafka-topic' CLI
- Delete in zookeeper like this:

  zookeeper-shell localhost:2181

  ls /brokers/topics

  _confluent-controlcenter-5-0-0-1-TriggerEventsStore-changelog, _confluent-controlcenter-5-0-0-1-error-topic, ...

  rmr /brokers/topics/yourTopicName

Now do a " kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181' and they should be gone for good.

OR, for the ABSOLUTE NUCLEAR OPTION:

- Attempt to drop your tables and streams from KSQL CLI
- Shut down KSQL server
- Shut down your brokers and zookeepers
- Delete eveything in the kafka logs dir on each broker node (location of dir is defined in your properties file).
- Start up your zookeepers again and delete the /brokers/topics from zookeeper CLI

Start everything back up and it should all be gone.  But be careful, you'll lose
everything, all your data.

Comment: Topics can be deleted using kafka-topics CLI - Thats not the problem. It's the tables and the streams that are still registered and that can't be deleted once a topic has been dropped (Registered = false).
NUCLEAR OPTION - There must be a better way to remove some dead streams / tables

Comment: So when you delete the backing topic from zookeeper they still exist as streams and tables in KSQL for you?

Comment: Thanks medloh for your comments.
- when I delete topics with 'kafka-topic' CLI then the topic is removed from kafka and from KSQL
- when I do this via zookeeper then the topic is removed from kafka but not from KSQL. 
- associated streams and tables in KSQL still exist

Comment: I feel your pain--topic, streams, tables, they all seem to hard to get rid of permanently.  Even with the nuclear option I describe above they sometimes come back later.  So I'm guessing there is a KSQL metadata store somewhere that persists that info.  Let me know if you make any progress on this, hopefully the next version will behave better.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to terminate any running queries first.

```
SHOW QUERIES;  --> that will show you the active queries (COPY QUERY ID)
```

Then:

```
TERMINATE [QUERY ID];
```

Then:
    DROP [TABLE OR STREAM];